# `UNIQUE constraint failed` on composite primary key despite use of trigger

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

Consider that we are getting a `UNIQUE constraint failed` error when trying to **insert** a new row into a table.

The row is made up of several primary keys which are linked to create a **composite key constraint**, namely made up of a combination of 4 fields `id`, `id_x`, `id_y` and `id_z`.

The first `id` key needs to be a `unique` key which is "auto-incremented" while `id_x`, `id_y` and `id_z` are `foreign keys`.

Since we cannot use the **auto-increment** feature on a **composite key** in sqlite we are resorting to the use of the following trigger where we lookup the highest integer for each field and add 1 in order to satisfy the **uniqueness** constraint:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [autoincrement]
         AFTER INSERT
            ON table_main
          WHEN NEW.id IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_main
        SET id = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_x = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_x) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_y = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_y) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_z = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_z) FROM table_main) + 1, 0);
END;
```

Despite this we are still getting `UNIQUE constraint failed` error.

UPDATE: `id_z` has a `forign key` constraint.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes giving DDL & example input & desired output & actual output including error messages. What did researching your error suggest? What does "several primary keys which are linked" mean? If you only want uniqueness of subrow values for the set of columns then you should not declare the individual columns themselves as PKs because that also says each is unique. Do you mean instead that the individual columns are each a FK? This is why MCVE. Also read re the role of NULL in UNIQUE & FKs.

Comment: I find it odd that before you insert a row in `table_main` you are updating ALL the rows in `table_main`. So maybe there's only one row in `table_main` in it's the next number controller for the `product_inventory` keys, in which case, wouldn't you want to fire the trigger before insert of `product_inventory`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion but `product_inventory` should have in fact been `table_main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since we cannot use the auto-increment feature on a composite key

The following has a composite key with an increasing unique id (what you have termed as auto-increment):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_main;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_fkx;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_fky;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_fkz;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [autoincrement];
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_fkx (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datacol TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_fky (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datacol TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_fkz (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datacol TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_main (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  id_x INTEGER REFERENCES table_fkx(id), 
    id_y INTEGER REFERENCES table_fky(id), 
    id_z INTEGER REFERENCES table_fkz(id), 
    UNIQUE(id, id_x, id_y, id_z)
);
/*
CREATE TRIGGER [autoincrement]
         AFTER INSERT
            ON table_main
          WHEN NEW.id IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_main
        SET id = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_x = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_x) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_y = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_y) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_z = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_z) FROM table_main) + 1, 0);
END;
*/

INSERT INTO table_fkx VALUES (10,'some data'),(33,'more data'),(56,'even more data');
INSERT INTO table_fky VALUES (73,'some data'),(1200,'more data'),(560,'even more data');
INSERT INTO table_fkz VALUES (15,'some data'),(1500,'more data'),(123456,'even more data');
INSERT INTO table_main (id_x,id_y,id_z) VALUES 
    (10,1200,15),(56,1200,15),(33,560,15),(10,73,15) -- etc
;
-- INSERT what could be a considered a duplicate but now is not as the autoincremnt(sic) makes it unique
INSERT INTO table_main (id_x,id_y,id_z) VALUES (33,560,15); -- i.e. same as 3rd
SELECT * FROM table_main 
    JOIN table_fkx ON id_x = table_fkx.id 
    JOIN table_fky ON id_y = table_fky.id
    JOIN table_fkz ON id_z = table_fkz.id
;
```

However, having part of the composite key unqiue, then means that you can effectively insert potentially useless rows that reference the same foreign keys.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but `product_inventory` should have in fact been `table_main`.

Comment: @AlexB the same fix applies (INSERT Or REPLACE along with AFTER INSERT instead of BEFORE INSERT). Question being updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not *despite* the trigger, but rather *because of* the trigger.

This updates *all* rows in `table_main` to the same key (when `NEW.id` is null). That will surely cause a constraint violation when there are 2 (or more) rows in `table_main`.

```
UPDATE table_main
        SET id = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_x = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_x) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_y = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_y) FROM table_main) + 1, 0),
        id_z = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id_z) FROM table_main) + 1, 0);
```

If `NEW.id` is not null, then the problem lies somewhere else.